# How do I run a website through selenium webdriver chrome instance which is blocked from my country

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, firefox, webdriver

I am trying to automate some scenario of a website which IP is blocked from my country.I can access the website and it's webelement through free VPN service which is an extension of chrome.After writing the code with webdriver and java when I want to verify the code through chrome driver instance then it unable to show the website content and show the IP block message.My question- is  there any way to automate and open this IP block website with chrome driver instance?

I need particular code/steps so that i can follow the steps and eradicate my problem.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the code you wrote.

Comment: There is a solution: 1. create manualy a new browser profile 2. install neccessary extenstion to the new browser profile 3. use the profile in selenium

Comment: Or you can use some simple proxy, but this can require an existing browser profile too.